# How can I suppress external app's messages using C#?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to run external app and suppress it's messages , That app showing a message when it completes a simple task , I need to suppress that message so I tried this :

```
  public void TrustMe()
        {
            string dir = Environment.CurrentDirectory ;
            using (Process ExternalProcess = new Process())
            {
                ExternalProcess.StartInfo.FileName = dir + @"\BaseetPath.exe";
                ExternalProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                ExternalProcess.Start();
                ExternalProcess.WaitForExit();
            }

        }
```

Edit :
I also tried this :

```
ExternalProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/quiet";
```

But the message still showing when I run the external app , How can I fix this ?
Thanks

Comment: What kind of app -- a console app or a Windows app? You can't prevent applications from showing windows (`ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden` is really just a hint). For a console application you can at least redirect standard output and standard error.

Comment: @JeroenMostert it's a windows app .

Comment: @JeroenMostert If I can't do it then how some people make silent installers and no messages show on screen ? is it different from just starting an app not install it ? Thanks for replying .

Comment: Installers usually offer options themselves for running silent. Something like passing `/quiet` needs to be built into the app itself. If the application insists on making noise, there's not much you can do to convince it not to. You can try executing it with `/?` to see if it offers any options.